# Why is used memory reported by free much less than resident usage for a single process as reported by top?

Tags: linux, memory, top

I have a potentially problematic application that *may* have memory leak issues. However, in the process of investigating this, I've come across what seems to be conflicting information.

When I use `free` to get a summary of memory usage on the server, there appears to be plenty of available RAM:

```
[alice@myserver]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.8G        2.4G        131M        3.6G        7.2G        3.5G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

However, if I use top to check the process of interest, it shows that single process using almost all of the available RAM:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16907 alice     20   0  158.6g   9.1g   7.6g S  63.2 92.8   6476:48 my_task
```

Even if I count all of used(2.4G) and shared(3.6G), that is still only 6.0G, much less than the 9.1G top says this single process is using.

Which do I believe, `top` or `free`?

Some additional details, in case they are relevant:

- OS is CentOS 7.7
- my_task is a Java application running JDK 15 with [ZGC](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/zgc/Main)
- my_task uses JNI and does allocate a lot of memory off-heap (1-2GB is expected, not 4 or 5GB)
- max heap size is 3GB, but VisualVM is showing the total heap to be ~2GB with only ~1GB allocated

Answer (score 2):

I turns out `top` is the one that is wrong, and it's due to ZGC.

> To avoid the overhead of masking pointers, ZGC involves multi-mapping
> technique. Multi-mapping is when multiple ranges of virtual memory are
> mapped to the same range of physical memory.
>
> ZGC uses 3 views of Java heap ("marked0", "marked1", "remapped"), i.e.
> 3 different "colors" of heap pointers and 3 virtual memory mappings
> for the same heap.
>
> As a consequence, the operating system may report 3x larger memory
> usage.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899020/zgc-max-heap-size-exceed-physical-memory
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926652/the-java-zgc-garbage-collector-uses-a-lot-of-memory

Comment: This is very interesting! Thanks for sharing!